# Elevator, friction, and horizontal force question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

[image]

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem.  I got answer A which is incorrect.  First I found the normal force acting on the computer to be 258N.  I then found the frictional force to be 90.3N.  Because you slide the computer at a constant rate, wouldn't this imply 0 acceleration in the horizontal direction, and thus the force to move the computer horizontally would only need to be greater than the frictional force of 90.3N?

Comment: How did you find 258N?

Comment: Normal Force = ma + mg, where a = 1.2 and g = -9.8

Comment: Now I see my error where I should have made gravity positive, but I don't really understand why because it acts downward.

Comment: If the elevator is accelerating upwards, where will the force on the computer point? Does it really become lighter?

Comment: $m\,a$ is inertia force so if you go upwards it must be negative, it act always opposite to the velocity. So the normal force is $m\cdot g+m\cdot a$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lift is going up, so the net acceleration as experienced by a body in the elevator is the resultant of acceleration due to gravity and the acceleration of elevator.

This means a, as experienced by a body in elevator is $$a=9.8+1.2=11 m/sec^2$$

the friction force is given by, $$f=μmg$$

by putting the values, $$f=0.350*30*11 $$

$$ f=115.5 N = 116 N (approx)$$